# python 3 PrettyTable

Tags: python, prettytable

How can I get my output in the table?

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import sqlite3

x = PrettyTable(["URL"])
x.padding_width = 1 

con = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\joey\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History')
cursor = con.cursor()
d = cursor.execute("SELECT URL FROM 'urls' ;")
for data in d:
    x.add_row([data])


print(x)
```

How can I add the output of my code in the table? This code is not working. 
The code under this text is good. But how can I get my output in this and not the `"test"`.

```
x = PrettyTable(["URL"])
x.padding_width = 1 

x.add_row(["test"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cursor returns tuples as you iterate over it. So instead of `[data]` (which would be a list containing a tuple), pass `data` itself to `add_row`:

```
for data in cursor:
    x.add_row(data)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for helping me! The output is really messy It doenst really like a table anymore haha. '+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------' Is kinda how my output looks now